# Throttling Popen() calls

Tags: python, multithreading, tabula

How much danger is there from starting too many processes with Popen() before the initial Popens have resolved?

I am doing some processing on a directory filled with PDFs.  I iterate over each file and do two things using external calls.

First, I get the an html representation from the Xpdf-based pdftohtml tool (pdfminer is too slow).  This makes an output of only the first page:

```
html = check_output(['pdftohtml.exe','-f','1','-l','1','-stdout','-noframes',pdf])
```

then if my conditions are met (I identify that it is the right document), I call tabula-extractor on it to extract a table.  This is a slow/long running process compared to checking the document and only happens on maybe 1/20 files.

if I just do `call(['jruby', 'C:\\jruby-1.7.4\\bin\\tabula', .....])`, I will spend a long time waiting for the extraction to complete while I could be checking more files (I've got 4 cores and 16gb of ram and Tabula doesn't seem to multithread).

So instead, I am using Popen() to avoid blocking.

```
Popen(['jruby', 'C:\\jruby-1.7.4\\bin\\tabula', '-o', csv, '-f', 'CSV', '-a', "'",topBorder, ',', leftBorder, ',', bottomBorder, ',', rightBorder, "'", '-p', '1', pdf]) 
#where CSV is the name of the output file and pdf is the name of the input
```

I don't care about the return value (tabula is creating a csv file, so I can always see after the fact if it was created sucessfully).  Doing it this way means that I can keep checking files in the background and starting more tabula processes as needed (again, only about 1 in 20).

This works, but it gets backlogged and ends up running a ton of tabula processes at once.  So my questions are:
Is this bad? It makes the computer slow for anything else, but as long as it doesn't crash and is working as fast as it can, I don't really mind (all 4 cores sit at 100% the whole time, but memory usage doesn't go above 5.5GB, so it appears CPU-bound).

If it is bad, what is the right way to improve it? Is there a convenient way to say, queue up tabula processes so there are always 1-2 running per core, but I am not trying to process 30 files at once?

Comment: 2 per core is excessive. I believe a good starting number is 1 per core + 1 (in case the others need a little I/O) for throughput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a convenient way to say, queue up tabula processes so there are always 1-2 running per core, but I am not trying to process 30 files at once?

Yes, the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module does just that.

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def process_pdf(path):
    subprocess.call(['jruby', 'C:\\jruby-1.7.4\\bin\\tabula', path, ...])

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)      # 3 processes
results = []
for path in search_for_files():
    results.append(pool.apply_async(process_pdf, [path]))
for result in results:
    result.wait()
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should be layering processes like that... maybe stick with threads (?). You'd want to use `concurrent.futures` in that case, though.

Comment: It seems to me that I would have to have my list of files first for this to work.  So I couldn't keep scanning through the list while spawning the tabula processes, I would have to do it in order.

Comment: @otto - You definitely want `multiprocessing`.  You need to look into the `Queue` class from that module to fully implement what you've described.  You'll spawn 2 - 3 consumers, your main process is your producer, and you add items to the Queue when they pass your initial criteria.

Comment: @otto Not to worry, we’ve got you covered—see updated answer.

Comment: I am trying to make this work.  It doesn't seem to be spawning only 3 processes.  Instead, it is spawning an infinite number of processes (if I watch the process list, it quickly goes from a base of ~100 to over a thousand in a few seconds).  It seems like it is not actually queuing the processes.

Comment: looks like this causes the module to import itself.  So you have to check if `__name__ == '__main__'` in order to prevent it from recursively running on top of itself.

Comment: @otto This is a discrepancy in how `multiprocessing` works between Windows and Unix. On Unix, the process is forked and the module is not re-imported. I forgot about this when throwing together this example on my Linux box, sorry.